# Knockout - Click Binding to Object Function - Scope Issues

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a simple collection of strings that I want to use Knockout's foreach binding to create buttons for. The button uses click binding to load some data in my object. The bindings happen correctly, but the actual load function fails, telling me that a method isn't supported.

Here's what I have:

```
//My Object
function MyObject()
{
    this.WorkerFunction = function(id)
    {
        //Do Work
    }

    this.Load = function(id)
    {
        //Call Another Function
        this.WorkerFunction(id); //Error: Object doesn't support property or method 'WokerFunction'
    }
}

//Creation
var myObject = new MyObject();

//VM Binding
var vm = ko.mapping.fromJS(jQueryAjaxObject);
ko.applyBindings(vm);

//HTML
<div data-bind="foreach: stringIDCollection">
    <button data-bind="click: function() { myObject.Load($data) }"> Load </button>
</div>
```

---

When a button is clicked, I get the following error: `Object doesn't support property or method 'WokerFunction'`. I had a similar error with a mouse move event elsewhere in my code, but I was able to solve that using the bind function like below. However, I am unable to get this to work for the Knockout binding.

```
$("myElement").mousemove(this.MouseMove.bind(this));
```

---

**Edit**

I have also tried `var self = this;` and `self.WorkerFunction(id);`, but I got the same results; the method isn't supported.

---

**Q: What is the correct way to handle a Knockout Click Binding to an object's function while maintain the this scope?**

---

Answer (score 2):

This is likely due to how you bind your event handler.  There are multiple ways to do so and each has its nuances, see official docs here:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html and context wrt `this` here: https://dzone.com/articles/knockout-click-binding-and

Answer (score 0):

You must store a reference to `this`.

Read about [how the `this` keyword works in JavaScript.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this)

```
// converted to commonly accepted coding style
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;

    this.workerFunction = function(id) {
        //Do Work
    };

    self.load = function(id) {
        self.workerFunction(id);
    };

    // do initialization here...
    self.stringIDCollection = ko.mapping.fromJS(/*...*/);
}

ko.applyBindings(new ViewModel());
```

---

Apart from that: Don't use JavaScript code in bindings. (Especially not entire functions. Not ever.) That's exactly the thing knockout has been designed to avoid.

Make `load` a method of your view model, like shown above

```
<div data-bind="foreach: stringIDCollection">
    <button data-bind="click: $root.load">Load</button>
</div>
```

Comment: Hey Tomalak. Thanks for the reply. I have also tried using self = this and I got the exact same result; the method isn't supported.

Comment: See my *"apart from that"* addition. You are not supposed to use JavaScript code in bindings.

Comment: The ViewModel that you've suggested doesn't work for my situation. The Knockout ViewModel is generated by the C# server and retrieved by jQuery, which returns a large and complex Javascript object to me; that's why I am using mapping. The myObject object with the Load function is an entirely separate object that does WebGL rendering; the only point of communication is the ViewModel telling the WebGL object what scene ID to render. So bringing all of my rendering code into my server generated ViewModel is not possible.

Comment: I see. That's the point where [custom bindings](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html) come into play. Write a binding called `render`, for example, and do your `myObject` calls there. You still are not supposed to a) write code in the `data-bind` attribute or b) create any kind of dependency from the view model to the view.

Comment: _"You are not supposed to use JavaScript code in bindings"_ -- on the contrary, the docs specifically provide examples of this and why you might want to do it:  http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html.  Those docs should also help anyone who ran into op's problem back in '13.

Comment: @Madbreaks Writing code into the bindings makes them hard to read, undermines the view/viewmodel separation and leads to corner-cutting the the viewmodel design. It's possible, but unclean. It should not be the first thing you try, but the last. You can, but you are not supposed to. Pick the wording you like best.

Comment: @Tomalak yeah yeah, I know.  Programming 101 dogma aside though you have not demonstrated how to retain `this` as a reference to the ViewModel in the bound function w/o using the inline approach.  And to that extent have not answered op's question. To further complicated things you continue to say "should" and "should not" without providing references to support those statements.  Not a hallmark of a good Answer, esp. after a (my) counter point does reference official docs.  Room for improvement here is all.

Comment: @Madbreaks I am not exactly sure what you want from me. Instead of berating me, write a better answer and don't steal my time with this hairsplitting. I have provided you with ample reason why I find writing functions into the view counter-productive, your opinions may differ, and that's all-right.

Comment: I'm not berating you, not at all. And I'm here because I'm *looking* for the correct answer.  So again, if you know how to answer the question while adhering to your own advice not to use inline functions, then that would be helpful to both me and future viewers.  I haven't been able to find how to do so.  Not sure why you feel this is some kind of personal affront, esp. given your rep.  It's not hairsplitting, your answer as it stands does not answer the question.

Comment: Look. Either you nitpick over the quality of this answer and how unsatisfactory you find it, or you have an actual question about knockout and ask it, preferably as a new question here on SO and not in the comment thread that is almost four years old. Currently I am inclined to believe that you mainly came here to prod me and don't actually have a question at all, and for that I don't have time. Anyway - you can also discuss an aspect of the problem in the comments, but *"hey this is all wrong not a hallmark of a good answer because I say so and now see that you fix it"* is a bad rather start.

Comment: In either case, I am not going to guess what your question might be and I'm absolutely not going to discuss whether writing functions into the view is a good idea or not. A useful handling of scope is one of the things you give up when you do that, and there are others, as I've outlined. If you positively *must* write functions into the view, you are on your own. My recommendation will always be "don't".